# Highlighting the highest and lowest point in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Could someone help me on changing the bullet or highlighting the highest and lowest values using amcharts?.

I am using serial chart. The condition given in the function "highlight" is matching , however the the bullets are not highlighted to the highest and lowest points..

Any help will be appreciated.

Please find my code below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
            var chart;

            var chartData = [
{"date": "2006", "value": 63, "value1": 87},
{"date": "2007", "value": 64, "value1": 63},
{"date": "2008", "value": 66, "value1": 75},
{"date": "2009", "value": 70, "value1": 51},
{"date": "2010", "value": 63, "value1": 79},
{"date": "2011", "value": 64, "value1": 65},
{"date": "2012", "value": 56, "value1": 52},
{"date": "2013", "value": 60, "value1": 88},
{"date": "2014", "value": 56, "value1": 90},
{"date": "2015", "value": 68, "value1": 83},
{"date": "2016", "value": 68, "value1": 63},
{"date": "2017", "value": 69, "value1": 74},
{"date": "2018", "value": 70, "value1": 68},
{"date": "2019", "value": 55, "value1": 65},            ];


            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY";
                chart.categoryField = "date";
                chart.addTitle("Graph Chart-Connects/ Disconnects");
                chart.addListener("rendered", highlight);


                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
                categoryAxis.minPeriod = "YYYY"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
                categoryAxis.inside = true;

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.tickLength = 0;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.showFirstLabel = false;
                valueAxis.showLastLabel = false;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Connects";
                graph.dashLength = 3;
                graph.lineColor = "#00CC00";
                graph.valueField = "value";
                graph.bullet = "round";
                graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Connects:[[value]]</span></b>";
                chart.addGraph(graph);


                // GRAPH
                var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph1.title = "Disconnects";
                graph1.dashLength = 3;
                graph1.lineColor = "#EF9B0F";
                graph1.valueField = "value1";
                graph1.bullet = "square";
                graph1.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Disconnects:[[value1]]</span></b>";
                graph1.fillToGraph = graph;
                chart.addGraph(graph1);

                // CURSOR
                var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
                chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
                chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
                chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

                // SCROLLBAR
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                // HORIZONTAL GREEN RANGE
                var guide = new AmCharts.Guide();
                guide.value = 10;
                guide.toValue = 20;
                guide.fillColor = "#00CC00";
                guide.inside = true;
                guide.fillAlpha = 0.2;
                guide.lineAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.addGuide(guide);


                var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                legend.marginLeft = 110;
                //    legend.data = [{markerType:"round",title:"Connects",color:"#EF9B0F"}, {markerType:"square",title:"Disconnects",color:"#00CC00"}]
                chart.addLegend(legend);
                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");




            });


            function highlight(event) {



                // get chart and value axis
                var chart = event.chart;
                var axis = chart.valueAxes[0];
                var graph = chart.graphs[1];

                if (chart.minMaxMarked)
                    return;




                // find data points with highest and biggest values
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];
                    console.log(dp[graph.valueField] + "<=>" + axis.maxReal);
                    //alert(axis.minReal);
                    if (dp[graph.valueField] == axis.maxReal) {
                           alert('test');
                        dp.markerType = "bubble";
                        dp.bulletSize = 8;
                        //dp.
                    }
                    else if (dp[graph.valueField] == axis.minReal) {
                       // alert('test');
                        dp.markerType = "bubble";
                        dp.bulletSize = 8;
                    }
                }

                // set flag that we're done already
                chart.minMaxMarked = true;

                // take in updated data
                chart.validateData();
            }


        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly setting the size/type parameters for high/low data points in data.

However, your graphs are not set up to use those fields.

To make the graph look for bullet type in data use its [`bulletField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletField) property. For bullet size: [`bulletSizeField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletSizeField):

```
graph.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize";
graph.bulletField = "markerType";

// ...

graph1.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize";
graph1.bulletField = "markerType";
```

Comment: hi martynasma, Thanks. Could you please be more specific where to add this property . Have already set  graph.bullet = "round"; and  graph1.bullet = "square";

Comment: hi , is this right?
graph.bulletSizeField = "30";                
graph.bulletField = "value";
graph1.bulletSizeField = "30";
graph1.bulletField = "value1";

Comment: not like this http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/xQxzq/. I need to set it dynamically after chart load

Comment: It would go into your highlight function: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5fc626a16b932e1e03983e117dc0da75

Comment: Thanks  martynasma. That is really helpful: please check this URL http://codepen.io/kthangabalu/pen/qZmReg . Need to highlight  max and min values for both orange and green lines. when i comment chart.addListener("rendered", highlightY1); highlightY1 is working fine and vice versa. Please see that there are three highlighted  points displayed displayed for GREEN line when you uncomment both addListener. Any ideas? please help. Check green arrows displayed wrongly  in Year 2009 and 2010. Any ideas.

Comment: You are using the same `bulletField` and `bulletSizeField` for both graphs. That's why the bullets are coming up on both graphs. http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b5406d66ecc56dbde934242fcd71a590/

Comment: Thanks!  martynasma. That worked!. Looks like i need spend more time on understanding amcharts scripts

Comment: OK. I suggest you delete this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196712/amcharts-issue-while-highlighting-min-and-max-value Let's keep SO clean.

Answer (score 0):

Solution posted martynasm !!! Thanks.

```js
   var chart;

            var chartData = [

                {"date": "2006", "value": 67, "value1": 83},
                {"date": "2007", "value": 70, "value1": 90},
                {"date": "2008", "value": 66, "value1": 56},
                {"date": "2009", "value": 65, "value1": 50},
                {"date": "2010", "value": 55, "value1": 90},
                {"date": "2011", "value": 60, "value1": 89},
                {"date": "2012", "value": 60, "value1": 52},
                {"date": "2013", "value": 61, "value1": 63},
                {"date": "2014", "value": 65, "value1": 74},
                {"date": "2015", "value": 64, "value1": 53},
                {"date": "2016", "value": 66, "value1": 61},
                {"date": "2017", "value": 60, "value1": 76},
                {"date": "2018", "value": 62, "value1": 65},
                {"date": "2019", "value": 61, "value1": 51},
            ];


            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY";
                chart.categoryField = "date";
                chart.addTitle("Graph Chart-Connects/ Disconnects");
                chart.addListener("rendered", highlightY1);
                chart.addListener("rendered", highlightY2);


                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
                categoryAxis.minPeriod = "YYYY"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
                categoryAxis.inside = true;

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.tickLength = 0;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.showFirstLabel = false;
                valueAxis.showLastLabel = false;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Connects";
                graph.dashLength = 3;
                graph.lineColor = "#00CC00";
                graph.valueField = "value";
                graph.bullet = "round";
                //graph.bulletSizeField = "30";
                // graph.bulletField = "value";
                graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Connects:[[value]]</span></b>";
                chart.addGraph(graph);


                // GRAPH
                var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph1.title = "Disconnects";
                graph1.dashLength = 3;
                graph1.lineColor = "#EF9B0F";
                graph1.valueField = "value1";
                graph1.bullet = "square";
                //graph1.bulletSizeField = "30";
                // graph1.bulletField = "bullet";
                graph1.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Disconnects:[[value1]]</span></b>";
                graph1.fillToGraph = graph;
                chart.addGraph(graph1);

                // CURSOR
                var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
                chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
                chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
                chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

                // SCROLLBAR
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                // HORIZONTAL GREEN RANGE
                var guide = new AmCharts.Guide();
                guide.value = 10;
                guide.toValue = 20;
                guide.fillColor = "#00CC00";
                guide.inside = true;
                guide.fillAlpha = 0.2;
                guide.lineAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.addGuide(guide);

                var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                legend.marginLeft = 110;
                //    legend.data = [{markerType:"round",title:"Connects",color:"#EF9B0F"}, {markerType:"square",title:"Disconnects",color:"#00CC00"}]
                chart.addLegend(legend);
                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");

            });


            function highlightY1(event) {
                // get chart and value axis
                var chart = event.chart;
               // var axis = chart.valueAxes[0];
                var graph = chart.graphs[0];
                
                graph.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize1";
                graph.bulletField = "markerType1";

                if (chart.minMaxMarked)
                    return;
                
                var connectsValue = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {                    
                    connectsValue[i] = chart.dataProvider[i][graph.valueField];                    
                }
                connectsValue.sort();                
                 // find data points with highest and biggest values
                 
                connectsMax = parseInt(connectsValue[connectsValue.length - 1]);
                connectsMin = parseInt(connectsValue[0]);
             
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];
                    
                    if (dp[graph.valueField] == connectsMax) {
                        console.log(dp[graph.valueField] + "<=>" + connectsMax);
                        dp.markerType1 = "triangleUp";
                        dp.bulletSize1 = 18;
                    }

                    if (dp[graph.valueField] == connectsMin) {
                        // alert('test');
                        console.log(dp[graph.valueField] + "<=>" + connectsMin);
                        dp.markerType1 = "triangleDown";
                        dp.bulletSize1 = 18;
                    }                    
                }

                // set flag that we're done already
                //chart.minMaxMarked = true;

                // take in updated data
               // chart.validateData();
            }
            
            
            function highlightY2(event) {
                // get chart and value axis
                var chart = event.chart;
               // var axis = chart.valueAxes[0];
                var graph1 = chart.graphs[1];
                
                graph1.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize2";
                graph1.bulletField = "markerType2";

                if (chart.minMaxMarked)
                    return;
                
                var disconnectsValue = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {                    
                    disconnectsValue[i] = chart.dataProvider[i][graph1.valueField];                    
                }
                disconnectsValue.sort();                
                 // find data points with highest and biggest values
                 
                disconnectsMax = parseInt(disconnectsValue[disconnectsValue.length - 1]);
                disconnectsMin = parseInt(disconnectsValue[0]);
             
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];
                    
                    if (dp[graph1.valueField] == disconnectsMax) {
                        console.log(dp[graph1.valueField] + "<=>" + disconnectsMax);
                        dp.markerType2 = "triangleUp";
                        dp.bulletSize2 = 18;
                    }

                    if (dp[graph1.valueField] == disconnectsMin) {
                        // alert('test');
                        console.log(dp[graph1.valueField] + "<=>" + disconnectsMin);
                        dp.markerType2 = "triangleDown";
                        dp.bulletSize2 = 18;
                    }                    
                }

                // set flag that we're done already
                chart.minMaxMarked = true;

                // take in updated data
                chart.validateData();
            }
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```