# Amcharts - Issue while highlighting Min and Max Value

Tags: amcharts

I need to highlight the min and max values of two 'YAxis' points of amcharts.
I am using "addListener" to highlight Y1 and Y2. The issue is an extra arrow is added in between Y2Min and Y2Max (Please check the screen shot)  and Y2Min is pointed downwards instead of upwards.

However when i comment addListener of highlightY1, highlightY2 works fine and vice versa. Can somebody help me to fix the the code? any help is appreciated

[Please check this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itz3g.png)

```js
 var chart;

            var chartData = [

                {"date": "2006", "value": 67, "value1": 83},
                {"date": "2007", "value": 70, "value1": 90},
                {"date": "2008", "value": 66, "value1": 56},
                {"date": "2009", "value": 65, "value1": 50},
                {"date": "2010", "value": 55, "value1": 90},
                {"date": "2011", "value": 60, "value1": 89},
                {"date": "2012", "value": 60, "value1": 52},
                {"date": "2013", "value": 61, "value1": 63},
                {"date": "2014", "value": 65, "value1": 74},
                {"date": "2015", "value": 64, "value1": 53},
                {"date": "2016", "value": 66, "value1": 61},
                {"date": "2017", "value": 60, "value1": 76},
                {"date": "2018", "value": 62, "value1": 65},
                {"date": "2019", "value": 61, "value1": 51},
            ];


            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY";
                chart.categoryField = "date";
                chart.addTitle("Graph Chart-Connects/ Disconnects");
                chart.addListener("rendered", highlightY1);
                chart.addListener("rendered", highlightY2);


                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set parseDates to true
                categoryAxis.minPeriod = "YYYY"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to DD
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.minorGridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true;
                categoryAxis.inside = true;

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.tickLength = 0;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.showFirstLabel = false;
                valueAxis.showLastLabel = false;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Connects";
                graph.dashLength = 3;
                graph.lineColor = "#00CC00";
                graph.valueField = "value";
                graph.bullet = "round";
                //graph.bulletSizeField = "30";
                // graph.bulletField = "value";
                graph.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Connects:[[value]]</span></b>";
                chart.addGraph(graph);


                // GRAPH
                var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph1.title = "Disconnects";
                graph1.dashLength = 3;
                graph1.lineColor = "#EF9B0F";
                graph1.valueField = "value1";
                graph1.bullet = "square";
                //graph1.bulletSizeField = "30";
                // graph1.bulletField = "bullet";
                graph1.balloonText = "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>Disconnects:[[value1]]</span></b>";
                graph1.fillToGraph = graph;
                chart.addGraph(graph1);

                // CURSOR
                var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
                chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
                chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
                chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

                // SCROLLBAR
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                // HORIZONTAL GREEN RANGE
                var guide = new AmCharts.Guide();
                guide.value = 10;
                guide.toValue = 20;
                guide.fillColor = "#00CC00";
                guide.inside = true;
                guide.fillAlpha = 0.2;
                guide.lineAlpha = 0;
                valueAxis.addGuide(guide);

                var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                legend.marginLeft = 110;
                //    legend.data = [{markerType:"round",title:"Connects",color:"#EF9B0F"}, {markerType:"square",title:"Disconnects",color:"#00CC00"}]
                chart.addLegend(legend);
                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");

            });


            function highlightY1(event) {
                // get chart and value axis
                var chart = event.chart;
               // var axis = chart.valueAxes[0];
                var graph = chart.graphs[0];
                
                graph.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize";
                graph.bulletField = "markerType";

                if (chart.minMaxMarked)
                    return;
                
                var connectsValue = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {                    
                    connectsValue[i] = chart.dataProvider[i][graph.valueField];                    
                }
                connectsValue.sort();                
                 // find data points with highest and biggest values
                 
                connectsMax = parseInt(connectsValue[connectsValue.length - 1]);
                connectsMin = parseInt(connectsValue[0]);
             
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];
                    
                    if (dp[graph.valueField] == connectsMax) {
                        console.log(dp[graph.valueField] + "<=>" + connectsMax);
                        dp.markerType = "triangleUp";
                        dp.bulletSize = 18;
                    }

                    if (dp[graph.valueField] == connectsMin) {
                        // alert('test');
                        console.log(dp[graph.valueField] + "<=>" + connectsMin);
                        dp.markerType = "triangleDown";
                        dp.bulletSize = 18;
                    }                    
                }

                // set flag that we're done already
                //chart.minMaxMarked = true;

                // take in updated data
               // chart.validateData();
            }
            
            
            function highlightY2(event) {
                // get chart and value axis
                var chart = event.chart;
               // var axis = chart.valueAxes[0];
                var graph1 = chart.graphs[1];
                
                graph1.bulletSizeField = "bulletSize";
                graph1.bulletField = "markerType";

                if (chart.minMaxMarked)
                    return;
                
                var disconnectsValue = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {                    
                    disconnectsValue[i] = chart.dataProvider[i][graph1.valueField];                    
                }
                disconnectsValue.sort();                
                 // find data points with highest and biggest values
                 
                disconnectsMax = parseInt(disconnectsValue[disconnectsValue.length - 1]);
                disconnectsMin = parseInt(disconnectsValue[0]);
             
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                    var dp = chart.dataProvider[i];
                    
                    if (dp[graph1.valueField] == disconnectsMax) {
                        console.log(dp[graph1.valueField] + "<=>" + disconnectsMax);
                        dp.markerType = "triangleUp";
                        dp.bulletSize = 18;
                    }

                    if (dp[graph1.valueField] == disconnectsMin) {
                        // alert('test');
                        console.log(dp[graph1.valueField] + "<=>" + disconnectsMin);
                        dp.markerType = "triangleDown";
                        dp.bulletSize = 18;
                    }                    
                }

                // set flag that we're done already
                chart.minMaxMarked = true;

                // take in updated data
                chart.validateData();
            }
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/kthangabalu/pen/qZmReg

Comment: martynasma has posted the solution, find the code below...http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b5406d66ecc56dbde934242fcd71a590/

Comment: Don't comment or answer. Please delete this question. It's a duplicate of your original question.